# Weird behavior of double-nested lists in R

Tags: r, list, nested

This just took me two hours of debugging to identify:

```r
> list1 = list()  # empty list
> list1['first'] = list(a=list(a1='goat', a2='horse'), b=42)  # double-nested
> print(list1$first$b)  
NULL  # Should be 42?
> print(list1)  # let's check the actual contents of list1
$first
$first$a1  # how did the contents of the innermost a-list end up here?
[1] "goat"

$first$a2
[1] "horse"
```

In this case, the list assigned to `'first'` becomes the list in `a` so `b` just disappears without warning. What is happening here, and where did the `b`value go?

I'm using R 3.0.2. How can I do something like this when R prevents me from doing the above?

Comment: `[` does sub-lists, `[[` does single elements. You're using the wrong one. Didn't you get a warning?

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely right. There is no warning when using single square brackets.

Comment: I get a warning in 3.1.2, maybe it's time to update your R version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As joran pointed out in a comment, the solution is to use double-brackets in the assignment:

```r
list1[['first']] = list(a=list(a1='goat', a2='horse'), b=42)
```

Apparently you get a warning in newer R versions but not in older, if you use single-brackets.